# Removing fields from the Media Uploader/Gallery

Tags: customization, wp-admin

I've been searching high and low for an answer.

I simply want to remove the Alternate Text, Caption, Description and Link URL-fields from the uploader and gallery view.

I seem that every thing else than this Media-thingy can be removed.

Thanx for helping out:)

Comment: This Trac comment makes it clear that the solutions below will no longer work.  Does anyone have an updated anser to this question?  http://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/22664#comment:7

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25894288/wordpress-remove-attachment-fields

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this via a filter. Add the following to functions.php. You can also add your own fields this way...

```
// edit fields in media upload area
add_filter('attachment_fields_to_edit', 'remove_media_upload_fields', 10000, 2);
function remove_media_upload_fields( $form_fields, $post ) {

    // remove unnecessary fields
    unset( $form_fields['image-size'] );
    unset( $form_fields['post_excerpt'] );
    unset( $form_fields['post_content'] );
    unset( $form_fields['url'] );
    unset( $form_fields['image_url'] );
    unset( $form_fields['align'] );

    return $form_fields;
}
```

The example above strips out more than you need to but if you do a `print_r()` on the `$form_fields` variable you'll see what's available to add/remove.

Comment: Doesn't appear to work any more.  $form_fields is empty for this filter.

Comment: Doesn't work on WP 3.5+

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately it looks like this changed quite a bit in WP3.5 when they upgraded the media library.  That filter's $form_fields parameter doesn't contain the defaults any more.  The only solution I've found so far is to forcibly remove the markup from the view using buffering:

*This is extremely fragile - any change to the WordPress core might break this*

```
function wpse45562_remove_media_fields( $buffer ) {
    // remove the 'caption' block
    $buffer = preg_replace( '~<p>\s*<label\s*for="attachment_caption">.*?</p>~ims', '', $buffer );
    // remove the 'alt text' block
    $buffer = preg_replace( '~<p>\s*<label\s*for="attachment_alt">.*?</p>~ims', '', $buffer );

    // remove the 'description' box (and label separately)
    $buffer = preg_replace( '~<div\s*id="wp-attachment_content-editor.*?</div>~ims', '',   $buffer );
    $buffer = preg_replace( '~<label\s*for="content">.*?</label>~ims', '', $buffer );

    return $buffer;
}

function wpse45562_media_strip_buffer_start() { ob_start("wpse45562_remove_media_fields");  }
function wpse45562_media_strip_buffer_end() { ob_end_flush(); }

add_action('admin_head', 'wpse45562_media_strip_buffer_start', 10, 1);
add_action('admin_footer', 'wpse45562_media_strip_buffer_end', 10, 1);
```

Comment: I think there a some filters in the js backbone templates where the fields get added we might be able to co-opt. It certainly isn't straightforward any more though :(

Comment: I agree.  For now I've opened a ticket over on Trac.  If they're going to make it the same as any other post it should respond to remove_post_type_support(), at least.

Comment: Wouldn't this approach affect caching?

Comment: @ThatBrazilianGuy - I'm not sure what you mean.  These fields are displayed in the dashboard.  Having empty values for the media will not affect the caching.

Answer (score 1):

Since WP 3.5, the simplest way is to just remove fields with CSS:

```
add_action('admin_head', 'custom_remove_attachment_fields');
function custom_remove_attachment_fields() {
    ?><style type='text/css'>
        .attachment-info .setting.has-description,/* Alternative Text */
        .attachment-info #alt-text-description,/* Alternative Text description */
        .attachment-info .setting[data-setting="title"],
        .attachment-info .setting[data-setting="caption"],
        .attachment-info .setting[data-setting="description"],
        .attachment-info .setting[data-setting="url"],
        .attachment-info .media-types.media-types-required-info /* Required info */ {
            display: none;
        }
    </style><?php
}
```

This is focused on images, but you can add anything to it...

Answer (score 0):

I know it's a really old question, but I was looking for a feature like this right now, and @Jake 's answer was the closest to the solution I got myself, which is adding to the style.css

```
.media-sidebar .setting.has-description,
.media-sidebar #alt-text-description,
.media-sidebar .setting[data-setting="title"],
.media-sidebar .setting[data-setting="caption"],
.media-sidebar .setting[data-setting="description"],
.media-sidebar .setting[data-setting="url"],
.media-sidebar .media-types.media-types-required-info,
.media-sidebar .compat-item {
    display: none !important;
}
```

this removed the whole meta fields part, leaving image details like file name, image size and upload date.

Answer (score -2):

The sanchothefat's Answer is correct, really Works like a charm.

Just for increase his answer, you can use `unset( $form_fields['image_alt'] );` to remove the Alternate Text.

Thanks for Answering sanchothefat, it Helped me.

Comment: Doesn't work on WP 3.5+