# How to use media upload on metabox post page without breaking TinyMCE?

Tags: custom-field, jquery, metabox, post-meta, uploads

I'm using the following code for upload in multiple mextaboxes in a post or page admin section. Works for metaboxes but breaks the TinyMCE insert image. I want to know please how I can achieve this without breaking the TinyMCE. Off course the issue comes when I overwrite the windows.send_to_editor function.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    jQuery('.st_upload_button').click(function() {
         targetfield = jQuery(this).prev('.upload-url');
         tb_show('', 'media-upload.php?type=image&amp;TB_iframe=true');
         return false;
    });
    window.send_to_editor = function(html) {
        imgurl = jQuery('img',html).attr('src');
        jQuery(targetfield).val(imgurl);
        tb_remove();
   }
});
```

A possible solution would be hiding "Insert into post" button which by the way is not to semantic in the metaboxes and put a new button like "Select image" and writing a function with take the img o attach url a assign to the input. How can I do that o something else you recommend?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

I was looking at [this answer](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/45581/6344) earlier. It shows you how to remove fields from the Media Uploader, so maybe it'll set you on the right lines for writing an additional function to incorporate into the Uploader?

Comment: Thanks dunc, this answer part of my question! I know how to remove elements from media uploaded now. Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

problem is you are overwriting `send_to_editor()` function. I have a similar question answered by `bainternet`. Never had time to test it out. Let me know if it works for you. [How to handle multiple instance of "send_to_editor" js function](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/50873/how-to-handle-multiple-instance-of-send-to-editor-js-function)